# Can't sign In with email and password with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I cannot authenticate with Firebase. This is my error:

```
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtp.zzb(Unknown Source)
com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdtw.zzb(Unknown Source)
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
com.example.limthy.icestudio.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Comment: Please add you the full exception.

Comment: This error typically occurs when the device or emulator you are running on does not have an up-to-date version of Google Play services installed.